# Not able to import data in salesforce from CSV file

Tags: data-import-wizard

I am trying to import data to an app I created in salesforce and not able to import. It is asking me to map salesforce object, but it is not showing salesforce object name which I had created rather it is showing its fields.

Comment: What type of object are you trying to import?

Comment: I have created a custom app where I am trying to import data from csv file.

Comment: Are you using the object which has two master-detail relationship??

Answer (score 0):

Try dataloader.io, read the documentation carefully or just watch the demo video http://dataloader.io/documentation

this tool is very good and easy for beginners. once you are comfortable and able to understand data management terms then you can move to using **workbench.io or dataloader tool** for free and unlimited data migration loading tasks.